# How to read values from an input file to the screen

Tags: c++

Is

```
cout.put(value);
```

valid for reading a value from a file to a screen in c++?

Comment: You can use `std::copy` with istream and ostream iterators to copy from a file to stdout. It works quite well if everything is one type.

Comment: This code will not work though?

Comment: There's no way to tell without context. All it does is write a character to the stream, which alone isn't nearly what you described.

Comment: It is in a do-while loop that gets the value from the input file then uses that code to output to screen.

Comment: As long as it's reading character by character, it should work. Did you try it? What did it do?

Comment: it only gave me one character the @ sign, that is not in my file.

Comment: any chance you could post a few more lines of your program, ideally stripping it down to demonstrate just *this* problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather ambiguous. Supposing the you have some data in the file(integers for example) you can extract them into local variable and print them out on the screen.

```
...
int k;
ifstream i;
i.open(yourfilename.txt);
k << i;
cout << i;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `value` is of a type that can be output by `cout`, then

```
cout << value;
```

should work just fine.